# How to communicate with Desktop Applications with python application (java, c++, vb api's available)?

Tags: java, python, c++, api, client

I am a mechanical engineer, a programming beginner and this is my first post - so apologies in advance.

I am interested in supplementing the functions in two different windows desktop applications (Polyworks and Creo 5.0) using Python.  I would want to use my python application to automate  internal tasks as well as interactively guiding users with a custom GUI.

Creo offers a Java api that has pretty decent coverage of different functions and a weaker VB api.  The Polyworks SDK "uses Microsoft’s COM architecture for most of the functionalities (additional functionalities are also offered through a C++-only API)".

In Creo - I have successfully executed sample programs interfacing with the program using VB, Java, VBA, and through calling internal macro language files (trail files) produced with Python.

I am interested in more general tips towards communicating effectively with desktop applications like these two through API's, using Python? Or whether one would expect great inefficiency in doing so?

What are the important first steps? Creating a library of functions, documenting normal usages and nesting of functions, and then beginning to scripting the calling of different modules created in Python?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Just to make it more real:

Creo Java API App example

```
import com.ptc.cipjava.*;
import com.ptc.pfc.pfcSession.*;
import com.ptc.pfc.pfcModel.*;
import com.ptc.pfc.pfcSolid.*;
import com.ptc.pfc.pfcModelItem.*;
import com.ptc.pfc.pfcFeature.*;
import com.ptc.pfc.pfcExceptions.*;

/**
 * The pfcInstallTest makes sure that J-Link has been properly
 * installed on your machine.
 * It test the pfc and cipjava package functionality
 * to make sure that those appear correctly in your CLASSPATH
 **/


public class pfcInstallTest{

  private Session proeSession;
  private int numberOfFeatures;
  private int numberOfModels;
  private Feature proeFeature;
  private Model proeModel;
  private Models proeModels;
  private ModelItems proeModelItems;

  public pfcInstallTest(Session inSession){

    proeSession=inSession;
    String ModelName = "pfcinstalltest"; 
    boolean status;

    status = loadModel(ModelName);

    //sleep 2 sec
    try{
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (status) 
      {
    //Print the information about each feature in the model
    //Test the functionality of the cip package using stringsequences
    // Test exception throwing/handling
    // Test action listeners
    // Unlooad the model
    status = getInfo() && testCIP() && testException() && testActionListeners() && unloadModel() && testSequences();

      }
    try
    {
        if (status)
          {
              proeSession.UIShowMessageDialog("Install Test Sucessful", null);

          }
        else
          {
              proeSession.UIShowMessageDialog("Install Test Has Failed", null);
          }
    }
      catch (Throwable e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
  }

  /**
   * This function loads the model and displays it in the Pro/E Session
   **/

  public boolean loadModel(String sampleName){
    ModelType mdl_type = ModelType.MDL_PART;

    try{
      ModelDescriptor proeModelDescriptor=
        pfcModel.ModelDescriptor_Create (mdl_type ,sampleName, "");
        printMsg("Created model descriptor: "+(sampleName)+ " type: "+mdl_type.getValue());

        proeModel = proeSession.RetrieveModel(proeModelDescriptor);
    proeModel.Display();
        printMsg("Model was retrieved)");
    }
    catch(jxthrowable x){
      printMsg("pfcException: " + x);
      x.printStackTrace ();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Polywork C++ Client App Example

```
/* *****************************************************************************
 * File: MainReadAndFit.cpp
 *
 * Description :
 *
 *      Defines the entry point for the console application.
 *      Reads an ASCII file of a point cloud containing points with coordinates and normals.
 *      The points are sent to PolyWorks|Inspector, and a sphere is then fitted to them.
 *      Then, the application verifies if the fit was successful after running a script MSCL.
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * InnovMetric Inc. Copyright ( C ) 2002
 *                            All rights reserved
 * ************************************************************************** */

// ===========================================================================
// INCLUDED FILES
// ===========================================================================
#include <comdef.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "PolyWorksSDK/COM/IIMInspect.h"
#include "PolyWorksSDK/COM/IIMInspect_i.c"
#include "PolyWorksSDK/COM/IIMPointCloud.h"
#include "PolyWorksSDK/COM/IIMPointCloud_i.c"
#include "PolyWorksSDK/COM/IIMSceneCamera.h"
#include "PolyWorksSDK/COM/IIMSceneCamera_i.c"
#include "PolyWorksSDK/COM/IMInspect_i.c"

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

// ===========================================================================
// CONSTANTS
// ===========================================================================
#define COEF        1
#define BUFFLEN     COEF* 1020

// ===========================================================================
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
// ===========================================================================
int nbImages = 0;

// color table
const int    GRP_RGBA_NB                     = 25;
const double _rgba_table[ GRP_RGBA_NB ][ 3 ] =
{
    { 1.0, 0.7, 0.7 },
    { 0.7, 1.0, 0.7 },
    { 0.7, 0.7, 1.0 },
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.6 },
    { 1.0, 0.6, 1.0 },
    { 0.6, 1.0, 1.0 },
    { 0.6, 0.8, 1.0 },
    { 1.0, 0.6, 0.8 },
    { 0.8, 1.0, 0.6 },
    { 1.0, 0.8, 0.6 },
    { 0.6, 1.0, 0.8 },
    { 0.8, 0.6, 1.0 },
    { 0.6, 0.6, 0.6 },
    { 1.0, 0.4, 0.4 },
    { 0.4, 1.0, 0.4 },
    { 0.4, 0.4, 1.0 },
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.2 },
    { 1.0, 0.2, 1.0 },
    { 0.2, 1.0, 1.0 },
    { 0.2, 0.6, 1.0 },
    { 1.0, 0.2, 0.6 },
    { 0.6, 1.0, 0.2 },
    { 1.0, 0.6, 0.2 },
    { 0.2, 1.0, 0.6 },
    { 0.6, 0.2, 1.0 }
};

// ===========================================================================
// FONCTION PROTOTYPES
// ===========================================================================
wchar_t* CharToWChar( const char* pSrc_, wchar_t* pDest_, size_t size_ );

int FillArraysFromFile( char*           filename_,
                        int             nbPoints_,
                        float**         aCoords_,
                        float**         aNormals_,
                        unsigned char** aColors_ );

int FillSafeArray( int             nbBlock_,
                   int             sizeBlock_,
                   float**         aCoords_,
                   float*          ppArrayCoord_,
                   float**         aNormals_,
                   float*          ppArrayNormal_,
                   unsigned char** aColors_,
                   unsigned char*  ppArrayColor_ );

int FillSafeArrayLast( int             startIdx_,
                       int             nbRemainPt_,
                       int             nbTPoints_,
                       float**         aCoords_,
                       float*          ppArrayCoord_,
                       float**         aNormals_,
                       float*          ppArrayNormal_,
                       unsigned char** aColors_,
                       unsigned char*  ppArrayColor_ );

int NbPointsFromFileGet( char* filename_ );

int Prompt( char* buffer );

// ===========================================================================
// FONCTION DEFINITIONS
// ===========================================================================

/* *****************************************************************************
 * Name: main
 *
 * Description :
 *
 *   Main routine
 *
 * Parameter: argc   : nb of arguments
 * Parameter: argv[] : array of arguments
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    //----------------------------
    // Initializes the COM library
    CoInitializeEx( nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED );


    //----------------------------
    //Global access to a PolyWorks|Inspector
    HRESULT     hr         =  0;
    IIMInspect* pIMInspect = nullptr;

    CLSID progID = CLSID_IMInspect;
    // With the line above, your program will attempt to connect exclusively with the version of PolyWorks|Inspector
    // you're currently working with. If the user upgrades to a more recent version of PolyWorks|Inspector, your program
    // will not attempt to connect to it.
    // Instead, to let your program attempt to work with the latest version of PolyWorks|Inspector installed on the
    // user's computer, uncomment the following line and make sure hr is not an error code before continuing.
    //hr = CLSIDFromProgID( L"InnovMetric.PolyWorks.IMInspect", &progID );

    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        progID,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_SERVER,
        IID_IIMInspect,
        ( void** ) &pIMInspect );

    if ( !SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are asking. Are you trying to access the Win32 API from Python/Java? Or do you want two separate applications to communicate with eachother on the same desktop ?

Comment: I want to access either of these two programs with python.  Query information, send commands, etc. How can I best use the api's of desktop programs?

Comment: Look into Pywin32 a python windows extension.